# How to configure google service key json file using .env configuration

Tags: firebase, github, environment-variables, google-cloud-functions

I am creating an webservice in nodejs using google service api key and during the development phase i've put the file locally and test like this ...everythink was ok.

Now i have to deploy in firebase and i have to make unvisible the configuration file . 
Do you have experience how to make this using .env file ?

The configuration file is like this :

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxxx-eeee",
  "private_key_id": "xxxw342234",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Now i access the file using this code :

```
const translate = new Translate(
    {
        projectId: 'my-project-0o0o0o0o'
        keyFilename: './my-project.json
    }
);
```

Who can help me with the steps that i have to access this file without publishing the credentials in github then in firebase

UPDATED 13.02.2020

i created .env file to store there my credentials like this :

```
 SEPA_TRANSLATE_PROJECT_ID="4354-4545"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_API_KEY_TYPE="service_account"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_PRIVATE_KEY_ID="43434"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMM=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_CLIENT_EMAIL="googletranslateaaaaapi@aaaaa-aaaa.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_CLIENT_ID="34234"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_AUTH_URI="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_TOKEN_URI="https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
    SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/googletranslatewerwer%erwerwre-werwr.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
```

now the my-project.json file look like :

```
{
      "type": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_API_KEY_TYPE,
      "project_id": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_PROJECT_ID,
      "private_key_id": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
      "private_key": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_PRIVATE_KEY
      "client_email": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_CLIENT_EMAIL,
      "client_id": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_CLIENT_ID,
      "auth_uri": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_AUTH_URI,
      "token_uri": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_TOKEN_URI,
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_KEY_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL,
      "client_x509_cert_url": process.env.SEPA_TRANSLATE_GOOGLE_SERVICE_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL
    }
```

this json is called :

```
 const translate = new Translate(
        {
            projectId: 'my-project-0o0o0o0o'
            keyFilename: './my-project.json
        }
    );
```

when i test my api i got this error message now : error translate text: SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use .env file on firebase cloud functions and can't use 
environment data like `process.env.xxxx` in json file.

You should use environment configuration for firebase cloud functions.

- To store environment data, you can use the `firebase functions:config:set` command.
- To get environment data, you can use the `functions.config()` function.
- Local setting file is `.runtimeconfig.json`, and run `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json` after store environment data.(`firebase functions:config:set` command)

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell#install_and_configure_the_cloud_functions_shell

If you want to only use translate API then the keyFilename is not necessary and don't make .env file yourself.

You should set up translate API authentication with a firebase service account.

And to run the local, you should set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the service Account JSON file that contains service account key.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"`

See:

- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate#readme.
- https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/setup-basic

And Could you try translate samples?

- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate/tree/master/samples
- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate/tree/master/samples#samples
- https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-translate/blob/master/samples/translate.js

Comment: yes i'm using cloud , but do you have instruction with .env file ...how to access this file and not to make public ?

Comment: I edited my answer. But my answer may be wrong. Could you try?

Comment: i updated again my question...seems easy with just a variable ...but in my case when i have a json file to store in env i can't do it...is not working for me :( i can figure it out what is going wrong

Comment: I edited my answer. Could you try translate samples?